# SSD not bootable in UEFI BIOS

Tags: boot, ssd, uefi

I am trying to make a clean debian distro install on my Lincplus laptop, which originally came with Windows. It is a fanless model with American Megatrend Aptio Setup Utility version 5.12 compliant UEFI 2.5. It comes with a stock emmc. I later added an SSD, which is perfectly detected during OS installation and shows in gparted.

Running my linux distro from the SSD is what I am trying to achieve. Not interested in Windows nor using the motherboard stock drive.

The problem is the machine won't boot up directly into the SSD.

So far, the BIOS can only pick up bootable partitions installed on either the emmc stock hard drive or external usb. The SSD is not even detected as a bootable option despite me having successfully created a bootable partition on it.

When trying to enter "Launch EFI Shell from filesystem device" in the BIOS, no filesystem is detected, which is rather odd since there is definitely an EFI bootable partition and filesystem on the SSD.

I cannot find any available documentation on what seems to be a rather new BIOS version with many touch points.

Question: how do I get this BIOS to boot up from my SSD instead of stock emmc?

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot in the bios if it has it, most do.

Comment: Secure Boot has been disabled but doesn't make any difference